# Connecting to AWS RDS via C#

Tags: c#, rds

I am trying to connect to MySQL AWS RDS using following simple C# code.

```
string cs = @"server=swift-test.czjkayncnfz9.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306;userid=*****;password=*****;database=swift-db";

var con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
con.Open();
```

But I get the following exception

**"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time
, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."**

The screenshots of my Inbound & Outbound rules are attached.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any EC2 instance in this setup?
If yes, then try referencing that security group in your inbound rules with the type as MySql/Aurora.

Comment: No I don't have an EC2 instance in this setup